# Multiple heroku applications for the same local application

Tags: heroku, hosting, subdomain, web-deployment

I have one application at my local machine and it's deployed to heroku. Or I must say, I was deployed - only a landing page. I have its own domain (`example.com`). However, it's in a test phase now and I want to deploy it to demo.example.com. I've already created another application for this at heroku (demo-example-com).

I could create a new local copy specially for `demo-example-com` but I don't think it's sensible. Instead I want to push the same local application to the different heroku **applicaions** (not accounts): `example.com` and `demo-example-com`.

How do I do this if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has good documentation on how to deploy to multiple environments from your local machine. In other words, how to push to different applications in the same account from one local repository. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments.